# Python Aiogram framework error type object 'State' has no attribute 'Form'

Tags: python, pycharm, aiogram

```
import logging

import aiogram.utils
import aiogram.utils.markdown as md
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters import Text
from aiogram.types import ParseMode
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State




API_TOKEN = '5813603682:AAHxbhe4tMIC3GxxO1Pi26PGn-ovtxW8k9M'

# For example use simple MemoryStorage for Dispatcher.
storage = MemoryStorage()

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize bot and dispatcher
bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

# States
class Form(State.Form):
    id = State()  # For example purpose
    text = State()  # Will be represented in `current_state`

@dp.message_handler(commands='start')
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):

    # Set state
    await Form.id.set()

    await message.reply("Привет! Введите ID пользователя, которому хотите отправить сообщение:")

# You can use state '*' if you need to handle all states
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals='cancel', ignore_case=True), state='*')
async def cancel_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Allow user to cancel any action
    """
    current_state = await state.get_state()
    if current_state is None:
        return

    logging.info('Cancelling state %r', current_state)
    # Cancel state and inform user about it
    await state.finish()
    # And remove keyboard (just in case)
    await message.reply('Операция отменена.', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.id, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def process_id(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Process user's ID
    """
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['id'] = message.text

    # Remove keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

    await message.reply("Теперь введите текст сообщения, которое хотите отправить:")

    @dp.message_handler(state=Form.id, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
    async def process_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        """
        Process user's ID
        """
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['id'] = message.text

        # Remove keyboard
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

        await message.reply("Теперь введите текст сообщения, которое хотите отправить:", reply_markup=markup)

        # Confirm validation
        await Form.next()

@dp.message_handler(state=Form.text, content_types=types.ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def process_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    """
    Process user's text
    """
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        text = data['text'] = message.text

    # Remove keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()

    # Send message to the user
    await bot.send_message(data['id'], text)

    # Remove state after the message is sent
    await state.finish()
    # And remove keyboard (just in case)
    await message.reply('Сообщение успешно отправлено!', reply_markup=markup)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Бот работает")
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Can't use Form in State class, just can't solve this. the error is

```
AttributeError: type object 'State' has no attribute 'Form'
ERROR:asyncio:Unclosed client session
client_session: <aiohttp.client.ClientSession object at 0x0000023E5281B690>
Exception ignored in: <function BaseBot.__del__ at 0x0000023E54F89760>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Богдан\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 33, in <module>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear, there's no such thing as `State.Form`. In the [examples](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/df294e579f104e2ae7e9f37b0c69490782d33091/examples/finite_state_machine_example.py), they use `StatesGroup` instead:

```
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import StatesGroup

class Form(StatesGroup):
    ...
```